# Which character encoding are being using in backend?

Tags: javascript, encoding, hex, character

I have a javascript variable that stores a url. I have to send that url to backend to do some operations, and as the URL may contain special characters, I convert it to hexadecimal to avoid problems. The backend code is not mine, I can not even see the code.

The encoding worked fine when I was trying with IPs, for example if I want to send '192.168.1.1' in JavaScript I encode it to '3139322e3136382e312e31' and backend understand it perfectly.

The problem comes when I try with a domain, then that backend expect and that I send does not match. If I want to send 'cstmal' in JavaScript I encode it to '6373746d616c' but the server waits '7066677A6e79'.

What is wrong? I have looked a lot, but I cant find an answer.

The code I use to encode is:

```
function encode(str) {
    var result = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
        result += str.charCodeAt(i).toString(16);
    }
    return result;
}
```

In short, do you know what character conversion gives this results:

c = 70
s = 66
t = 67
m = 7A
a = 6E
l = 79

Thank you!

Comment: How do you know what the server "waits"?  I seriously doubt that that's an actual encoding of the characters you think it's encoding.

Comment: When I make an create operations, a link is created in BD with the domain converted. There I see what they are doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strange as it may sound, the data appears to be rot-13 encoded. For example, cstmal becomes pfgzny in [rot-13](http://www.rot13.com/info.php), and when you replace the characters by their Ascii codes as two hexadecimal digits, you get 7066677A6e79. The JavaScript implementation is simple but see e.g. [4umi Rot13](http://4umi.com/web/javascript/rot13.php).

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK most encodings use the same codes for alpha-numeric characters (1-128 range), so if it works for numbers it should work for a-z characters as well. If you know what codes server returns for every letter, you could build own mapping, like create an object `{'c': '70', 's': '66', ...}` and use it to encode strings.

Comment: Is not a good solution but is the best solution for me. Very much thanks for the idea.